# ngx-translate: Find all missing keys passed through translate pipe in the whole project (unit test)

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, ngx-translate

I want to write the ONE unit test for the whole project (not for one specified component) in order to check if there are any missing keys (in my .json file with all translations), which I pass through translation pipe ANYWHERE in the project. For example:

```
<span>{{ 'FOO' | translate }}</span>
```

If FOO key doesn`t exist in .json file, then the test should fail and (optionally) somehow return the list of missing keys. Is it possible to implement this feature in this way? Or at least in other comparable ways?

Comment: It depends on how complete/accurate you expect it to be. For instance if what's left of `| translate` is the result of a function or even expression (e.g. 'FOO'.replace(...) | translate) you won't be able to find them all. Similarly, if you use regular expressions to find the strings they have to fit some format (e.g. on same line as `| translate`). With these restrictions you could do this.

Comment: I just want to know where and how to I can analyse and check ALL of the passed strings through the translate pipe (in all html files of the project, already processed if it was expression).